# Append to csv file every time script is triggered using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a list of dictionary. So every time the script is triggered the list i.e.'my_list' will be appended to csv.

eg. [example_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1icv.png).

But when script is triggered second time with the second set of values column name is again pushed.

eg. [example_2nd_trigger_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIvzV.png)

CSV I want using pandas is like eg. [requirement_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdrms.png) with column names too.

Condition that every time script runs it will have some 3 field values like 'fff',45,'rrr' and different every time.

So, I tried creating list of dict and then append list into csv but result is not as expected.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = [{'name':'someuser','id':111}]
def generate_csv_report(my_list):
    try:
        filepath = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop",'user.csv')
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
        df.to_csv(filepath, mode='a', index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))

generate_csv_report(my_list)
```

Can someone help me with the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from csv import DictWriter

my_dict = {'name':'someuser','id':111}
filepath = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop",'user.csv')

def generate_csv_report(file_path, dict_of_elem, fieldnames):
    # Open file in append mode
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        dict_writer = DictWriter(write_obj, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        # Add dictionary as wor in the csv
        dict_writer.writerow(dict_of_elem)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
for i in range(5):
    generate_csv_report(filepath, my_dict, my_dict.keys())
```

I hope this solution works for you. Note that I have replaced the list with a dictionary.

Comment: name and id column name should also be printed along with values in csv file